# jqgrid saving records for inline editing

Tags: jqgrid

in jqgrid for inline editing when we click the save icon, ** internally it calls the saveRow method, but i want to call my custom method where i will implement my save logic as well calling to controller method.**

i used below code for grid.

```
var grid = jQuery("#list5").jqGrid({
            url: '/home1/GetUserData',

                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "POST",
                colNames: ['Code', 'LoginID', 'Emailid', 'CreateDate', 'PostalCode', 'Mobile'],
                colModel: [
                            {name: 'Code', index: 'Code', width: '16%', editable: true, sortable: true },
                            { name: 'LoginID', index: 'LoginID', width: '16%', editable: true, sortable: true },
                            { name: 'Emailid', index: 'Emailid', width: '16%', editable: true, 

        sortable: true },
                              ],
                    rowNum: 10,
                    height: '100%',
                    scrollOffset: 0,
                    rowList: 10,
                    shrinkToFit: true,
                    pager: $("#pager2"),
                    editurl: "/home1/EditUserData",
                    caption: "Simple data manipulation"
                });
                jQuery("#list5").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: false, add: false, del: true, search: false, refresh: false }, {}, {}, { url: '/home1/DeleteUserData' });
                jQuery('#list5').jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager2', { edit: true, add: true},
                });
            });
```

so please anyone let me know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your requirements. [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) has a lot of customization possibilities. You can rename all parameters which will be sent to the server using `prmNames` option of jqGrid. Using `extraparam` parameter of [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) you can specify additional information which can be sent to the server. The callback `serializeRowData` can be used to implement your custom serialization. For example you can convert the data to JSON. Using `aftersavefunc` you can make some custom actions after the data will be successfully saved on the server. So I recommend you use the features instead of implementing your custom `saveRow` method.

**UPDATED**: If you want to have navigator icon which uses your custom `saveRow` you should don't add "Save" button by [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#inlinenav). You can use `save: false` option of [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#inlinenav). Then you can just use [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) and add your custom icon which look exactly like original "Save" button and make call of your "custom `saveRow`" in the `onClickButton` callback.

Comment: thanks, i already tried extarmam of saveRow, actualy i have written custom library to generate the grid markup and neccessary scripts based on user settings, there i got this requirement to call user specific method on save not the saveRow method.

Comment: @Meraj: What exactly do the custom library? An example could show whether such work is really required and whether your implementation is error free. Are you sure that it will still work if you update jqGrid to the next version? If you want to have navigator icon which uses your custom `saveRow` you can just use [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) and make the call in the `onClickButton`.

Comment: thanks alot for ur update. custom library means just like triand.web.mvc.dll we are building our own cutom dll to make grid at run time. its a specific requirement by user. so not worried about future updates we already discussed with him.  i already used navButtonAdd for this.

Comment: @Meraj: You are welcome! The code which you posted has no usage of `navButtonAdd`. It contains only `navGrid` and `inlineNav`. If you already call your custom implementation of `saveRow` from `onClickButton` of `navButtonAdd` then I don't understand your current question. Is the problem solved which you describe in the question?

Comment: yes oleg, the code is not showing navButtons because initially i didnt used the navButtons and exrtremely sorry that later also i didnt updated the code. yes my problem is solved because of ur initial suggetions only.

Comment: Oleg: actualy i accepted the answer by clicking on the accepted answer icon, but when i again login to see further comments it was it was unchecked dont know why.