# JQGrid: How to override saveparameters url for inlineNav addRow?

Tags: url, jqgrid, inline

I need to explicity specify the url for adding a row via inlineNav.

But, I do not know HOW to do that, other than something called saveparameters has the url value I need to specify, documented here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing&s[]=addrowparams

However, function that uses that is saveRow, and that is called by inlineNav save button using default saveparameters, which has wrong URL (the window location, because grid has not editurl specified).

QUESTION: How can I configure jqGrid saveparameters with the url my inlineNav save button needs?

I could put 8 or 10 URLs here showing many asking same question and no answer.  Is this stupid question, or not supported or possible?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This says prmNames can be used to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363523/jqgrid-saving-records-for-inline-editing, but I look at prmNames documentation here, http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options&s[]=prmnames.  But, saveparameters is not given in that description.

Comment: You should post your code and/or a jsfiddle. But if you are using something like this, jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('inlineNav',pagerid, parameters);, parameters here accepts addParams : {}. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing, about half way down, where it reads inlineNav. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, getting down about this stuck in it.   First, I have no code because I don't know what to code to do this!  I am looking into how to extend jggrid defaults, but I think that will be global and I must do this on per-grid basis.  Second, URL you gave shows saveparamaters I am talking about, but inlineNav save button calls saveRow.  I have to call saveRow myself in order to present url I want.  I am hoping configurable way for inlineNav so I do not have to program my own.  Seems reasonable to be able to do this, but not clear to me reading doc w/ no examples.

Comment: On url you gave above, 'parameters' after pagerid to inliveNav has table of parameters you can specify, add, addicon, addtext, addtitle, etc.  I see no way how to specify url for add.  Or, an 'addParams' has not a 'url' option, only parameters =
{
    rowID : "new_row",
    initdata : {},
    position :"first",
    useDefValues : false,
    useFormatter : false,
    addRowParams : {extraparam:{}}
}  saveRow has the 'url' parameter, but inlineNav out-of-the-box calls it with null url, therefore grid editurl is used.  How to specify saveRow url for saveRow w/o custom programming?

Comment: From the doc on addRow->addRowParams : (object) parameters which are passed to the addRow - they are the same as of editRow, so addParams : {addRowParams : {url:'something'}} should work. But you should at least code something that doesnt work, it'll help you better phrase your questions...

Comment: Understood. But, I have to programmatically call editRow in order to specify editparameters.   Maybe I'll have to put custom buttons to programmatically call editRow, saveRow, addRow.  But, I was looking for a way to call inlineNav and use out-of-the-box functionality, just override url for add and edit.  I have tried this, same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569809/jqgrid-inlinenav-with-different-urls-for-edit-and-delete-buttons?rq=1  and it didn't work for me either.

Comment: When you say it doesnt work, what is happening? Have you debugged with firebug? Also, https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js is the code for the latest jqgrid. Walking through it, it seems as if this functionality is implemented, the only thing I could see is if the useFormatter option is true, it uses params from the colmodel->formatoptions instead.

Comment: Yes, debugging with Firebug I have found this is due to some compatible mode in the code.  jqgrid's saveRow does 1 of 2 things based on if argument is object or not.  What I've had to do is avoid inlineNav and use addfunc to call my own function that does an .addRow.  Then, display a button in 1st column of grid to save row, which calls .saveRow.  Now, I can specify .saveRow url parameter.  However, .saveRow always overrides resetoreAfterError even though I set it to false, because .saveRow using compatible mode where 1st arg not object so it set restoreAfterError to false. (v4.5.4)

Comment: So, my problem is two-fold: grid always restores inline editing of new row - even though I said NOT to.  But, original problem: I can't use out-of-the-box inlineNav to just save a record to a url I want.  With 1st problem I true both ways of calling API, neither works to get 1st arg used to prevent defaults taking place.  I am no javascript expert, so learning while debugging what the problem is.

Comment: .saveRow in v4.5.4 of jqgrid is causing me difficulty - how to call so that I can override restoreAfterError to false.  I try both API calling methods and still debugger shows always $.extend so that restoreAfterError true is used.

Comment: I am not sure how to help you debug this problem, maybe with a fiddle? But an alternative solution to your problem would be to use the inlineNav as is, with one url for edit and add, and in that url redirect/invoke to the actual edit or add url. jqgrid sends a oper request variable indicating edit or add.